# Netbeans run JPQL query not working

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, netbeans, jboss

I have made `CRUD` application using `EJB`+`JPA` using `JBoss` server, which works perfectly fine. But I am unable to [run](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/test-jpql-with-netbeans-ide-73-tools) `JPQL` query in netbeans from persistence file. Please find below configuration.

**JBoss 7 datasource :**

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jboss/darshan" pool-name="com.discusit.darshan_darshan-ejb_ejb_1.0PU" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/darshan</connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>darshan</user-name>
        <password>darshan</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

**persistence.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="com.discusit.darshan_darshan-ejb_ejb_1.0PU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/darshan</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Kindly note, I am able to auto complete my tables but when I run I found below errors.

> java.lang.Exception: You need to add your persistence provider library
>   either to project classpath or registed as Ant Library within Netbeans

or

> java.lang.Exception: You need to specify either database connection or
>   datasource in persistence.xml.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have `valid instance of your application server` (your case JBoss) in Servers under Services tab.
2. in your application `Properties -> Run : Select your server (JBoss)`.
3. Make sure that you have `valid Database connection` to your schema in Databases under Services tab (be sure that it has same credentials as in your Data Source configuration in your application server).
4. Insure that you have already `added your entity classes` in your persistence.xml.
5. Download your JPA provider library, and add it to your Project from

   `Properties -> Libraries : Add Library`.

In case you use maven :

just add dependency of your `JPA provider`

(insure that you NOT include this tag **`"<scope>provided</scope>"`** during running JPQL, but add it before compiling as your application server will provide it).

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it work...

1. Payara 6 (Jakarta namespace)
2. done
3. It is and working, credentials the same
4. done
5. I hope this part of my tests struggling:
   provider dependency

   ```
    <dependency>                        
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>                        
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>           
    </dependency>
   ```

If I add `<scope>provided</scope>`, running JPQL query I get this error:

> java.lang.Exception: You need to add your persistence provider library either to project classpath or registed as Ant Library within Netbeans

without `<scope>provided</scope>` I get this error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named lt.ke_KV-IoT
> at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)

how to make it work??